# sentry Does not work when i deploy project on the server

Tags: django, server, celery, development-environment, sentry

I have a Django project with sentry configurations.
when i run project in my local, i can see errors in my sentry panel, but when i push the project on server and run it, i cant see the errors in sentry panel.
This is my config code

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration
from sentry_sdk.integrations.celery import CeleryIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://********@****.ingest.sentry.io/*****",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), CeleryIntegration()],

    # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    # of transactions for performance monitoring.
    # We recommend adjusting this value in production.
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,

    # If you wish to associate users to errors (assuming you are using
    # django.contrib.auth) you may enable sending PII data.
    send_default_pii=True
)
```

I also dockerized the project, and I had a problem with Gunicorn that I was able to fix, but it still sentry doesn't work when I run the project on the server.

Comment: If you add `debug=True` to your call to sentry_sdk.init() what log messages do you see in your console when you visit a view that throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases people says that setting sentry parameters `send_default_pii=False` helps or `debug=True`
I have similar issue, Sentry works when uwsgi started by hand but does not work when process started by Fabric.